# how can i reduce the execution time for this code

Tags: algorithm, c++11, sum

the problem is that the user enters N,1<=N<=1000000,then N lines and a Q number 1<=Q<=1000000 then Q lines each contains two space separated a,b numbers.For each  line i need to print total of numbers from i entred from line a to b.
for example i enter:

```
5     // N
1     // First line
2     // Second line ... to fifth
3 
4
5
3    // Q
0 4  // the two numbers a, b... Q times
1 3
2 2
```

the output will be

```
15 // from 0 to 4 : 1+2+3+4+5=15
9  // from 1 to 3 : 2+3+4=9
3  // from 2 to 2 : 3
```

my code takes more than 5 second to execute if Q and N are big 100000

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int a,b,c,p1,p2,sum(0);
vector<int>t(0);
cin>>a;
for(int i(0);i<a;++i)
{
    cin>>b;
    t.push_back(b);
}
cin>>c;
for(int i(0);i<c;++i)
{
    sum=0;
    cin>>p1>>p2;
    sum=accumulate(t.begin()+p1,t.begin()+p2+1,0);
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your program works correctly and has only performance problems, https://codereview.stackexchange.com will be a better place to ask the question. Make sure to read that site's guidelines for asking questions: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking.

Comment: Hint: don't store actual numbers, store running totals `S(i)==x_0 + ... + x_i`. Then a sum from `a` to `b` is simply `S(b) - S(a-1)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because improvement of working code belongs in CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than saving the numbers in an array and computing the totals each time, compute a running sum and store that sum in the array.

For example, given the numbers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], your `t` vector will contain `[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]`. You can easily modify your code to build that:

```
int sum = 0;
t.push_back(sum);  // see discussion below
for(int i(0);i<a;++i)
{
    cin>>b;
    sum += b;
    t.push_back(sum);
}
```

Then, when asked for a sum, it's a simple matter of subtracting the value that comes *before* the starting index from the number at the ending index. For example:

```
1,3 : result = t[3] - t[0]
2,2 : result = t[2] - t[1]
```

If the starting index is 0, then you don't subtract anything at all. The reason I pushed a 0 sum to the vector first is to handle the case when `p1 = 0`. Otherwise I'd have to special-case that. (Thanks to @max66 for the suggestion.)

Your compute loop becomes:

```
for(int i(0);i<c;++i)
{
    cin>>p1>>p2;
    sum=t[p2+1] - t[p1];
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Comment: to simplify (IMHO): add a zero (`t.push_back(0)`) before the push back cycle; the `result` become `result = t[p2+1] - t[p1];`; avoiding the `if ( p1 > 0 )` test.

Comment: actually this method is working but it steel take more than 5 seconds to execute if the Q and N are really big i don't think its impossible to execute in less than 5 sec because this exercise is on a online judge so when it input a big Q and N it gives  TLE wich means that the execution time is out of limit

Comment: @HaytamRahimi: Consider pre-allocating your vector to size `a+1`. That will prevent having to re-allocate memory as the vector grows. If that's still too slow, then replace your vector with a pre-allocated array.